# Custom calculation for extracting week number, month and year in R without manual intervention

Tags: r, date, lubridate, strftime

How do I extract week number, week beginning Sunday date, month and year that follows a custom calendar?
For e.g
Fiscal Week# 1 for 2016 begins on 2015-12-27 and ends on 2016-01-2 (Sun-Sat)
Fiscal Month# 1 for 2016 begins on 2015-12-27 and ends on 2016-1-23
Fiscal Year 2016 begins from 2015-12-27 and ends on 2016-12-31

My data set already includes a 'Date' column in the format y-m-d. I was hoping to get a one time code that will account for all years (2016,2017,2018,2019..) and dates to come irrespective of date ranges within the data set.

I attempted to use the code below but it didn't work since the first date range in my data set begins on a Monday (2016-04-04). Will appreciate any guidance since I am a beginner in R

```
require(lubridate)  
DropGTRow$FW <- as.numeric(strftime(DropGTRow$Date, format = "%U")) + 1  
DropGTRow$FY <- as.numeric(strftime(DropGTRow$Date, format = "%Y"))  
DropGTRow$FM <- as.numeric(strftime(DropGTRow$Date, format = "%m"))  
DropGTRow$FW_Date <- as.numeric(strftime(DropGTRow$Date, format="%m/%d/%y"))  
DropGTRow$Weekday <- weekdays(DropGTRow$Date)
```

Preferred Output:

```
Date        FW  FW_Date    FM   FY  
4/4/2016    15  4/3/2016    4   2016  
4/5/2016    15  4/3/2016    4   2016
4/6/2016    15  4/3/2016    4   2016
4/7/2016    15  4/3/2016    4   2016
4/8/2016    15  4/3/2016    4   2016
4/9/2016    15  4/3/2016    4   2016
4/10/2016   16  4/10/2016   4   2016
4/11/2016   16  4/10/2016   4   2016
4/12/2016   16  4/10/2016   4   2016
4/13/2016   16  4/10/2016   4   2016
4/14/2016   16  4/10/2016   4   2016
4/15/2016   16  4/10/2016   4   2016
4/16/2016   16  4/10/2016   4   2016
4/17/2016   17  4/17/2016   4   2016
4/18/2016   17  4/17/2016   4   2016
4/19/2016   17  4/17/2016   4   2016
4/20/2016   17  4/17/2016   4   2016
4/24/2016   18  4/24/2016   5   2016
12/27/2015  1   12/27/2015  1   2016
12/28/2015  1   12/27/2015  1   2016
12/29/2015  1   12/27/2015  1   2016
12/30/2015  1   12/27/2015  1   2016
12/31/2015  1   12/27/2015  1   2016
1/1/2016    1   12/27/2015  1   2016
1/2/2016    1   12/27/2015  1   2016
1/3/2016    2   1/3/2016    1   2016
1/4/2016    2   1/3/2016    1   2016
```

Comment: Add some example code using `dput()`...

Comment: Hi Martin- apologies, I have not used dput() before- are you looking for a sample data set or the lubridate code which I have included in the question? The data set has normal calendar dates beginning 2016-04-04 and all i need is new dimensions which has calculated weeks, month and year. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `dput(head(DropGTRow))`

Comment: thanks...updated as part of the question. Does this help?

Comment: We are getting closer ;) This is basically just about the `Date` column right? Just subset your data for the columns relevant to solve your problem and add THAT data in your question. Currently there is only 1 row.